# are you allowed to feed fish on shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, eating, fish

I've heard one may feed an animal on shabbos but may not feed a fish,being that tthey could live a day without food, is that accurate?

Comment: Humans can live a day without food too.

Answer (score 6):

[Yalkut Yosef 1:373:15](http://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulkhan_Aruch_Yalkut_Yosef.1.373?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) says that one may feed fish in his fishtank on Shabbos.

> מותר ליתן אוכל לדגים שבאקווריום בשבת

[Rabbi Chaim Tabasky](http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=2391) also says it is permitted.

This is only permitted for pet fish. One may not feed fish in a lake or ocean on Shabbos as they are not his responsibility. [OU.org - Feeding the fish](https://www.ou.org/torah/machshava/tzarich-iyun/tzarich_iyun_tashlich/)